# swift parse json error "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\")."

Tags: json, swift

I am attempting to parse the following json data:

```
{
        "id": 123,
        "url": "https://www.google.com",
        "title": "The Google link",
        "created_at": "2017-08-29T04:00:00.000Z",
        "sent": true,
        "alternative": "https://google.com",
        "things": [],
        "description": [
            "search",
            "lookup"
        ],
        "company": "Alphabet"
 }
```

Below is my struct:

```
struct site: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let title: String
    let created_at: String
    let sent: Bool
    let alternative: String
    let things: [String]
    let description: [String]
    let company: String
}

let sites = try JSONDecoder().decode(site.self, from: data)
```

I continue getting the error:

> "keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\")."

Is this due to the json information being an array?.How would I be able to parse this information?

Thank you for any and all feedback.Sorry I have corrected the title to reflect the correct error.

Comment: I see no problem , sure that `id` is always `Int` ?

Comment: yes id is always an Int

Comment: What is the source of data (which is of type Data), and how are you confident that the data example shown is the actual content?

Comment: Is this the complete JSON? Or you are just showing a part of it?